# cv2.warpPerspective() is returning an empty image

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, opencv3.0, opencv, python

I am trying to get the cv2.warpPerspective() of an image but i am getting nothing instead.

***Code:***

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
import operator




src = cv2.imread(r'D:\D_Apps\Sudoku Solver\image\Sodoku.jpg' , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
gaus = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, (9,9),0)
proc = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gaus, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
proc = cv2.bitwise_not(proc,proc)
kernel = np.array([[0., 1., 0.], [1., 1., 1.], [0., 1., 0.]],np.uint8)
proc = cv2.dilate(proc, kernel)

contours, h = cv2.findContours(src.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
polygon = contours[0]

bottom_right, _ = max(enumerate([pt[0][0] + pt[0][1] for pt in
 polygon]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
top_left, _ = min(enumerate([pt[0][0] + pt[0][1] for pt in
 polygon]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
bottom_left, _ = min(enumerate([pt[0][0] - pt[0][1] for pt in
 polygon]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
top_right, _ = max(enumerate([pt[0][0] - pt[0][1] for pt in
 polygon]), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

crop_rect = [polygon[top_left][0], polygon[top_right][0], polygon[bottom_right][0], polygon[bottom_left][0]]


top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left = crop_rect[0], crop_rect[1], crop_rect[2], crop_rect[3]
src = np.array([top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left], dtype='float32') 
side = max([np.linalg.norm(bottom_right- top_right), np.linalg.norm(top_left- bottom_left),np.linalg.norm(bottom_right- bottom_left), np.linalg.norm(top_left- top_right)])

dst = np.array([[0, 0], [side - 1, 0], [side - 1, side - 1], [0, side - 1]], dtype='float32')
m = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
cv2.warpPerspective(src, m, (int(side), int(side)))

cv2.imshow('image',src)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This code returns this:
just a window with no image inside.

[image: this is just a window with nothing inside]

this is the output can someone please help me with this?

Comment: "just a window with no image inside" -- Nope. Open the screenshot in some image editor and zoom in -- there is a tiny image, something like 3 pixels wide and 6 pixels tall. Inspecting the shape of `src` should confirm that. Time to do some debugging.

Comment: oh yeah u r rught thanks a lot

Comment: @DanMašek I can't increase the size can you help me with that? I changed the size variable in warpPerspective but it's still showing the same image.